# Account locked after adding line on /etc/passwd file

Tags: sudo, users, non-root-user, etc, passwd

I have installed this version of Ubuntu on my laptop.

```
└─ $ ▶ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Because of my limited knowledge regarding Linux, I have added
a line manually to `/etc/passwd`
My user which I login to the laptop is `gofoboso` with a password.
This user has sudo rights.
After adding the second line into the contents following, I do not have sudo rights.

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/usr/bin/zsh
gofoboso:x:0:0:gofoboso:/gofoboso:/usr/bin/zsh
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

I understand that the passwords are encrypted on the `/etc/shadow` file, and now this has the exact attributes as the root user has (??)

```
   ─ $ ▶ sudo cat /etc/shadow
    [sudo] password for gofoboso: 
    Sorry, try again.
    [sudo] password for gofoboso: 
    sudo: account validation failure, is your account locked
```

This is the company's laptop and I do not have the root password.
I've tried some commands I found online but all of them required sudo.
Anyone knows how can I revert this ? Most importantly I cannot restart the laptop or shut it down, because it will ask the password of the user `gofoboso`, which probably it's the same as root's now ??
If it cannot be fixed without becoming root, If someone knows the root password, and deletes that line the gofoboso user will be enabled again?

Thanks.

Comment: Your new user has some UID but not same name as `root`, so it will have same rights, basically super administrator of the laptop, no need of sudo anymore. You previously add sudo rights to **edit** `/etc/passwd` but you do not have root password? Strange setup as you have the same rights. Next time use `adduser` or `useradd`, depending on distribution, to create new accounts. It is almost always a bad idea to edit `/etc/passwd` and/or `/etc/shadow` directly by hand.

Comment: BTW, when you are issuing the sudo command, and it asks for the password; it is not asking for the root password, it is asking for the sudoer password. Just to be clear.

Comment: Yes, Octavian I enter my password, which was working before the change I did on the /etc/passwd file, but it's obviously not working anymore.

Comment: ``gofoboso:x:0:0:gofoboso:/gofoboso:/usr/bin/zsh`` another thing borked in that line is the home directory ``/gofoboso`` ([the second to last column](https://linux.die.net/man/5/passwd)). You probably want it to read ``/home/gofoboso`` instead. Traditionally only ``root`` has their home dir in the filesystem root.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get into 'single user mode'. You can eithe issue the command 'init 1', or reboot it and gain single user access by modifiying the grub entry; (you'll have to add the word 'siingle' as the last word on the kernel line).

Comment: Thanks, but can you please elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: I've searched the single user mode, I understand if you get into the recovery mode, you choose the root shell prompt. Will I get asked the root password for the last one ?

Comment: Good question. you might.  If so then try adding "rw init=/bin/bash"  to the kernel line

Comment: As long as they haven't disabled single user mode form the grub menu, you should be fine. Please refer to this:  https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_reset_a_root_password

Comment: Which is the kernel file you 're referring to ? How do I access it, and does it need sudo rights ?

Comment: While booting the system the GRUB2 menu will be displayed, to boot the system using bash follow these steps:
........
Use the arrow keys to select the boot entry you want to edit.
Press e to start editing that entry.........
Use the arrow keys to go to the line that starts with linux or linux16.
........
Go the the end of that line add a space then rw then another space and init=/bin/bash........
........
Press Ctrl-x or F10 to boot that entry

Comment: just refer to this page; it gives very thorough details:
                    https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_reset_a_root_password

Answer (score 0):

You wrote, "*I have added a line manually to `/etc/passwd`*" and "*I do not have the root password*".

If you have rights to edit `/etc/passwd` you already have root permissions - at least somewhere - even if you don't have the root password itself.

Because of your description I'm going to assume that you edited the password file like this:

```
sudo vi /etc/passwd    # NEVER DO THIS, even with a different editor
```

The `sudo` command can be configured to provide root permissions (and in this case clearly does so, because editing `/etc/passwd` requires root permissions to succeed). So you can almost certainly tell it to give you a root shell directly:

```
sudo -s      # Start a shell
sudo bash    # Start "bash"
```

From here you can either reset the root password, or simply do whatever it was that you needed root permissions to do.

Generally speaking, adding a second root-equivalent user account is not useful. You shouldn't be logging in to a privileged account, and tools like `doas` and `sudo` provide a managed gateway to privileged actions.

Incidentally, editing the `/etc/passwd` file should be done with the `vipw` command which sanity-checks the edited password file before installing it. (You can also safely edit `/etc/group` and `/etc/shadow` - see `man vpiw` for the details.)

```
sudo vipw                # Safely edit the passwd file with the default editor
sudo EDITOR=nano vpiw    # Use "nano" to edit the file safely
```

In your case what was probably missing was an entry in `/etc/shadow` and maybe one in `/etc/group`. Adding these won't automatically make every tool work correctly with your new user account because some (wrongly) check for the user name `root` instead of the UID `0`.

---

If you have managed to break the only login to your system, you will need to boot a rescue system (I like [SystemRescue](https://www.system-rescue.org/)) and use that to fix the broken entry in your system's `/etc/passwd`. There are many questions and answers on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) that address this